# How to save a backup of mails sent through MIME::Lite in Perl 5?

Tags: mime, perl

I am sending mail through MIME::Lite perl module.I want that my sent mails should be saved in Sent items folder of my mail inbox.Please suggest me a way to do this.
Thanks
script-

```
use MIME::Lite;

my $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
    From    => 'xyz@abc.com',
    To      => 'abcd@gmail.com',
    Subject => 'sending mail',
    Type    => 'multipart/mixed',
);

$msg->attach(
    Type     => 'TEXT',
    Path     => '/home/user/myName/cppLab/a.txt',
    Filename => 'aabc.txt',
    Disposition => 'attachment',
);

$msg->attach(
    Type     => 'TEXT',
    Data     => "learning to send mail",
);


 #$msg->print(\*STDOUT);
  #$msg->print_header(\*STDOUT);
 $msg->send;
print "mail sent.."
```

Comment: Which Perl are you using?

Comment: @Přemysl Šťastný  I am using perl 5.12.5

Comment: Do you send your email using SMTP AUTH? (smtp with password) Do you access your mailbox via IMAP protocol? Your problem has "a few" special cases.

Comment: I have attached my script

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you access your inbox. In any case, you'll probably need `MIME::Lite`'s `as_string` method that you can call on messages to retrieve the entire text including headers and possibly attachments.
For local mailboxes:

- If your mail folders use the Maildir format, you could use [`Maildir::Lite`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Maildir::Lite) to simply write the returned string to an appropriately named (`Maildir::Lite` does that for you) file.
- For mbox folders, have a look at [Mail::Box::Mbox](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Mail-Box/lib/Mail/Box/Mbox.pod)

Local mailboxes can be handled in just a few lines of Perl. If your inbox is remote and needs IMAP, there's always `IMAP::Client` but I don't really have a clue about it. Perhaps a local Maildir plus [offlineimap](http://www.offlineimap.org/) would do, too?